# Ajax/jQuery/Json pass variable but I get [object Object] error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to pass an array with json in php:

```
$array = array ($a, $b, $c);
echo json_encode($array);
```

and to use it in jquery like this:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api.php',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var id = data[3];
            var vname = data[1];
            $('#description').html("<b>id: </b>" + id + "<b> name: </b>" + vname);
        }
    });
});
```

But this prints as "id: [object Object] name: [object Object]" instead of the values I want, I get that..

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for any help..

Comment: It seems like `$a`, `$b` and `$c` are objects (or associative arrays). `[object Object]` is **not** an error, it's the default string representation of an object. But, `id` should be `undefined`, since your array has only three elements. Anyways, we cannot really help you without knowing the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[object Object]` means that `$a`, `$b` and `$c` are objects. To print out an object in javascript you should use `data[index].variable` where `variable` is the property of the object. Try to `console.log(data)` to see what you get: you should see 3 objects. Expand them, and read the variables inside of them.

Also, since you're array is made of 3 elements, `data[3]` should not exists. You should post more PHP code.

Comment: being called "sir" at 21 years old sounds a bit strange! xD
Glad it helped, cheers.

Comment: btw, you can also do that beforehand in PHP with `$a = $a->value;`.